# Hessian of sigmoids

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, hessian-matrix, scalar-fields

I have $q = f^{T} A f$, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix and $f$ a $n \times 1$ vector output of a sigmoid function

$$f = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-w^T X}}$$

I want to take the seconder order derivative of (Hessian) $q$ w.r.t vector $w$ which is a $p$-dimensional vector. Hence $X$ is an $n \times p$ matrix. So far, I've only succeed in the computing the first order derivative using the chain rule, which I found to be as follows:

$$\frac{dq}{dw} = 2(Af)^{T}DX$$

where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with its diagonal entries equal to $f_{i}(1 - f_{i})$ Checking the result of the above gradient against automatic differentiation tools, it is correct.  However, I'm stuck at this step to get the seconder order derivative of $q$. How can I move from the gradient and get the hessian of the quadratic form? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bit confused with your notation.  $w^TX$ should be a vector, what does it mean when you write $e^{-w^TX}$ and $f = \frac1{1+e^{-w^TX}}$?

Comment: @Guangliang $f$ is a vector-valued function that takes n-dimensional vector and for each component of the vector computes $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-z}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found, the gradient writes
$\mathbf{g}
= 2 \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{A} \sigma(\mathbf{Xw})$ where
$\mathbf{D}=\mathrm{diag}[\sigma'(\mathbf{Xw})]$.

It follows
$d\mathbf{g}
= 
2 \mathbf{X}^T [\mathbf{D}_1+ \mathbf{D} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{D}] \mathbf{X} d\mathbf{w}
$
where $\mathbf{D}_1
=\mathrm{diag}[\mathbf{A} \sigma(\mathbf{Xw}) \circ\sigma''(\mathbf{Xw})] $

The (symmetric) Hessian is
$\mathbf{H}=2 \mathbf{X}^T [\mathbf{D}_1+ \mathbf{D} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{D}] \mathbf{X} $

Maybe this expression can be simplified a bit.

Comment: Can you please explain how the expression $D_{1} + DAD$ was derived?

Comment: In the gradient term, both $\mathbf{D}$ and $\sigma$ depend on $\mathbf{w}$. This implies two terms when taking the differential because of the product rule.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Define a few useful variables
$$\eqalign{
p &= \exp\LR{Xw},\;&P=\Diag p &\qiq dp = PX\:dw \\
f &= \fracLR{p}{\o+p},\;&F=\Diag f &\qiq df = \LR{F-F^2}X\:dw \\
Y &= \Diag{Af} \\
}$$
Use these to calculate the differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
q &= f^TAf \\
 &= A:ff^T \\
dq &= A:\LR{f\,df^T+df\,f^T} \\
 &= \LR{A+A^T}f:\c{df} \\
 &= 2Af:\c{\LR{F-F^2}X\:dw} \\
 &= 2X^T\LR{F-F^2}Af:dw \\
\grad qw &= 2X^T\LR{F-F^2}Af \;\equiv\; g \\
}$$
The Hessian is the gradient of $g$
$$\small\eqalign{
dg
 &= 2X^T\LR{\c{dF}-2F\,\c{dF}}Af + 2X^T\LR{F-F^2}A\:\c{df} \\
 &= 2X^T\LR{I-2F}\,\Diag{df}\:Af + 2X^T\LR{F-F^2}A\,df \\
 &= 2X^T\LR{I-2F}\,\Diag{Af}\:df + 2X^T\LR{F-F^2}A\,df \\
 &= \BR{2X^T\LR{I-2F}Y + 2X^T\LR{F-F^2}A}\,\c{df} \\
 &= 2X^T\BR{\LR{I-2F}Y + \LR{F-F^2}A}\c{\LR{F-F^2}X\:dw} \\
\grad gw
 &= 2X^T\BR{\LR{I-2F}Y\LR{F-F^2} + \LR{F-F^2}A\LR{F-F^2}}X \\
}$$
It is easy to see that the Hessian is symmetric since $A$ is symmetric
and $\{I,F,Y\}$ are diagonal.

---

$\sf NB\!:\:$ Colons used in the gradient derivation denote Frobenius products, i.e.
$$A:B = \trace{A^TB} = B:A$$